# Footer is gone when `tcblisting` contains `\pause`

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I'm trying to prettyprint a `beamer` slide with `\pause` in it using the `tcblisting` environment. It shows the listing first and then the compiled result. The problem is that the page footer is gone for the first frame (displayed before the `\pause`).

The MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Pause in a listing}
\begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}
\begin{itemize}
  \item The first item
  \pause \item The second item
\end{itemize}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document
```

Is there a way of getting the footer back? Or may be I'm doing something wrong here? The working `\pause` is a desirable outcome.

Here are the first and the second PDF pages that come from this example:

[image: Frame 1]

[image: Frame 2]

Comment: Perhaps `\item<2-> The second item` is a better way here

Comment: Or if you want this automatically for all items: `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`

Comment: Right, `\item<2->` certainly works, and it'll be at the next slide. But is there a way to make `\pause` work as well?

Comment: @SergeiGolovan In my opinion: `\pause` is a very crude command. In the long run, you will gain more possibilities and fine control if you use alternatives.

Comment: It's an example of a technique in `beamer`. Even if I write "Don't ever use it", I'd like to demonstrate it first (or may be this footer problem can be used as a live demo of its shortcomings?)

Comment: @SergeiGolovan `tcolorbox` and `\pause` don't seem to be friends, another example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326585/36296

Comment: Found a workaround based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/pause-in-tikzpicture-breaks-footline. Added the following option: `after lower=\onslide<1->` to the `tcblisting` environment.